# Apache Beam logs messages with the wrong tags

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

**Error** logs don't log in the GCP console.
**Warning** logs do log as info (so I've been using them to log info messages).  E.g.,

```
test = "hello debug world" 
logging.warning("%s", test) # will log as info message in GCP dataflow console
```

**Info** logs don't log in the console either.

I'm using Apache Beam Python 3.7 SDK 2.23.0, [but this seems to be an old issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63252013/8062488).

Also happens by Apache Beam SDK itself, which logs errors silently at times as info.

[image]

Any idea what's causing this? Seems to be a bug on the Apache Beam side of things more than an scripting error.

Comment: Are you using Python? According to the documentation (https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/logging#java:-sdk-2.x_4) you can change the log level for Java but not for Python

Comment: I believe this may have something to do with it, yes.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to change the drop down value from Info to some higher log level to see `Error` or `Warning` type messages. In the screeenshot the log level is set to Info and you are searching for a string error in the log entries and stackdriver is filtering based on it.

Comment: The thing is that, when I do so, they aren't there. That is, if I log warning messages my self, switching the dropdown doesn't show them. They just don't work. Sorry for not pasting more screenshot about that.